# MacOSX cuts off stdin at 1023 chars

Tags: mac, stdin

How can I change the limit? I don't know how to change the tty in mac terminal. Are there any way to do it? I also cannot use pbpaste in my python input.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are doing and what is happening ?

Comment: I just want to input in python, but I can only input 1023 charactors.